# Crystal Report - avoid Logon after server install

Tags: crystal-reports

How I can fix the Crystal Report to update directly from the datasource.
I'm using dataset to the rpt; after installing the report in another PC in the runtime, when loading the report it shows username and password.
Actually I solved manually in the PC by opening the report and make verify from the dataset.

Any ideas ???

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Are you passing data from a .net application via a Dataset or is the report going directly to the datasource?

Did you do a verify dataset or verify Database to fill the problem manually?

Comment: yes i'm using .net application and i make always verify database from rpt...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a valid xsd for your .Net objects and your dataset.